# How I can make sub-query in mongoose same as mysql?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subquery, mongoose-schema

I am new in mongo. I have a problem in project to make sub query in mongo same as mysql. Please check below.

I have 2 collections

Collection 1 -> Questions

```
{
    "_id":"5ee9357528232c325c57b0f5",
    "question": "What is true happiness ?",
    "status": 1,
    "category_id": "5ee9352d28232c325c57b0f1",
    "created_at": "2020-06-16T21:11:17.795Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-06-16T21:11:17.795Z",
}
```

Collection 2 -> submit_answers

```
{
    "_id": "5ee94254674c5f26043745c8",
    "answer": "True happiness is the happiness of soul",
    "status": 1,
    "user_id": "5ed5f3db4ca9ff26e4dfc972",
    "question_id": "5ee93bc5b3d8d828f01e4ced",
    "created_at": "2020-06-16T22:06:12.509Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-06-16T22:41:58.295Z"
}
```

Now I want to check get all the questions with answers submitted by users. If user not answer for any question it will appear as null. I think this SQL query will better explain that what's my problem.

```
let user_id = 1

SELECT *,(SELECT answer FROM submit_answers sa WHERE q.question_id=sa.question_id AND user_id="user_id") as answer FROM questions q
```

I don't want to use loop because it will slow down response. Because I have 200+ questions.

Please help me to solve this

Comment: In MongoDB this is done via aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Hi @D.SM , Thanks for reply. Can you please give me sample code for mongoose. I use with aggregation  but I don't know in details about aggregation. Please help me to sort it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found its answer. Check out below.

It works same as my Sql Query

```
let user_id = 1

SELECT *,(SELECT answer FROM submit_answers sa WHERE q.question_id=sa.question_id AND user_id="user_id") as answer FROM questions q

let questions = await Question.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    status: 1,
                    category_id: categories[i]._id
                }
            }, {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'submit_answers',
                    let: {question_id: "$_id", user_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id)},
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $and: [
                                        {
                                            $eq: ["$question_id", "$$question_id"]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            $eq: ["$user_id", "$$user_id"]
                                        },
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $project: {
                                "answer": 1, "_id": 1, "status": 1, "created_at":1
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    as: "answer"
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: {
                    "path": "$answer",
                    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
                }
            }
        ]);
```